# Debugging React component lifecycle stacktrace

Tags: reactjs, debugging, lifecycle

Is there a friendly way to debug what causes a component render method executed?

Here is the stack trace with a breakpoint in `render` method of a deep nested component:

[image: call stack]

Is there any existing dev tool / library can provide more information from that stack trace? For example:

[image]

Comment: You should be able do this using an HOC. For existing tools, check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/visible-react.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but IMO, HOC requires code changes. There must be a better, more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Maybe this utility can help - https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-did-you-update. It monkey patches React itself so you don't need to change code all over.